# A 60s-70s movie where a woman crashes spaceship, later stalked and kidnapped by man

Tags: story-identification, movie

Can anyone help me find this movie! I believe the movie was about a woman who crash a spaceship or a saucer in i think a jungle like scenery, and was kidnapped by this man that kept stalking her. The guy i think had orange small circle glasses on. And the girl had long hair. I belived the girl was rescued by a group of men and said she had been the trauma. The woman then becomes his wife or something. The movie went on with action of themed parties and undercover hunts. Thats all i can remember. It was a color based film. And it came on in cartoon colors i think. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you remember any character names by any chance, possibly a planet name?

Comment: They were on earth. It was a 60s 70s type thriller vibe. Kinda like a mob movie. But with futuristic fashion.

Answer (score 4):

"Zeta One"(1969)? 
A.K.A. The Love Factor.

It has the alien woman, the 'undercover hunts', futuristic outfits, the guy with the 'small circle glasses', and it has a kind of mob movie vibe. Click below to watch the trailer.

And if this is the movie please forgive me!

Comment: This seems to be it, but its not. Thank tho lol.